# Allow users to install games through steam without giving them admin access

Tags: windows-8, installation, administrator

I'm the family's tech support and I'm looking for a way to not give my brother admin access, yet allow him to install things from his steam library without me having to remote in every time he want's to install a game.

I'm using steam as an example, but would probably also allow this technique with [ChocolateyGui](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/SysAdmins/OS/Windows/all-new-chocolateygui/) as I generally trust the chocolatey packages to take out the [toolbars etc](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadWrappersAndUnwantedSoftwareArePureEvil.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would say somewhere in the security tab wich you can find in the properties menu when you right click on your steam shortcut.

What you're looking for is done with ACL's. Acces Control Lists.

Comment: Would that allow the installs that are spawned by steam to run as admin?